# How to configure DNS for microsoft odbc driver for oracle (in 64 bit arch.)

Tags: java, oracle11g, dns, odbc

I try to configure DNS for odbc running `c:/windows/syswow64/odbcad32.exe`.
After choosing microsoft ODBC for ORACLE it ends with this error :

> the Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found . These
>   component are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part  of the
>   Oracle version 7.3(or greater) client software installation
>
> you will be unable to use this driver untill these have been
>   installed.

I installed  oracle 11g on my pc but it doesnot helps.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing something while configuring DNS. Is PATH variable correct in your environment variables? PATH variable should include ORACLE_HOME/bin directory. I am just predicting simple mistakes that we do.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application is 32-bit / 64-bit. If it is 64-bit, you can't connect to 32-bit Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle as they're different architecture, both must match. Besides that, MS didn't provide 64-bit ODBC Driver for Oracle, but you can use the driver provided by Oracle.

If your application is 32-bit, you need to install 32-bit Oracle client too. Same concept. The architecture must match.